# What is this error in PyTables?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am using `pytables` via `pandas` in python. I am trying to load a file using `pandas.read_hdf()` but I am getting this nasty error. I hope I have not lost my 1.1 gigs of irreplaceable data. I have not seen any errors during the saving process. Everything seems to be working fine.

Can someone explain what this error is saying?

Also, is there any way to recover?

```
HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5Dio.c", line 174, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "H5Dio.c", line 449, in H5D_read
    can't read data
  File "H5Dchunk.c", line 1729, in H5D_chunk_read
    unable to read raw data chunk
  File "H5Dchunk.c", line 2755, in H5D_chunk_lock
    unable to read raw data chunk
  File "H5Fio.c", line 113, in H5F_block_read
    read through metadata accumulator failed
  File "H5Faccum.c", line 254, in H5F_accum_read
    driver read request failed
  File "H5FDint.c", line 142, in H5FD_read
    driver read request failed
  File "H5FDsec2.c", line 720, in H5FD_sec2_read
    addr overflow, addr = 1108161578, size=7512, eoa=1108155712
```

Comment: your file is corrupted. i have only seen this when someone tries to write using multiple processes/threads which is strictly verboten.

Comment: I posted a similar question which you answered, and the multiple processes problem is not impossible. I thought it might be different in this case because I did not see the same errors as before, and the error itself is different.

Comment: I have seen this happen even with a disk hiccup. HDF5 is quite good, but it behooves backups :)

Comment: OK, thanks. If you want to answer this question w a link to the other question (to help anyone who gets those different error messages) I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523985/opening-a-corrupted-pytables-hdf5-file/31525689#31525689)

bottom line. your file is borked. no way to recover from this. this is specifically warned against (using multiple threads/processes as writers). see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#notes-caveats).

HDF5 is NOT threadsafe/process safe for writers.